# How to deal with same keys in HashMaps ?

Tags: java, hashmap

Hello fellow soldiers.

Obviously keys in hashmaps are **unique**. However, I've been trying to write a code that reads a csv file and then puts the key and value in the map. However, there are keys the same (every key is like 15 times in the csv file). In that case, it should make a sum of the values, and just return the key once. 
How to do that? My code right now is as follows.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line;



    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)); 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {

        System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage() + "Bestand niet gevonden!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //this is where we read lines
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitter = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            if(splitter[0] != "Voertuig") {

                alldataMap.put(splitter[0], splitter[8]);

        }


            //MIGHT BE JUNK, DONT KNOW YET
            /*if((splitter[0].toLowerCase()).contains("1")){
                double valuekm = Double.parseDouble(splitter[8]);
                license1 += valuekm;
                System.out.println(license1);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }*/


        }
        System.out.println(alldataMap);
        TextOutput();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println(ioex.getMessage() + " Error 1");
    } finally {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

So if I have the following info (in this case its the 0th and 8th word read every line in the csv file)

```
Apples; 299,9
Bananas; 300,23
Apples; 3912,1
Bananas;342
Bananas;343
```

It should return

```
Apples;Total
Bananas;Total
```

Comment: Isn't there a more simple way? Like first looking whether splitter[0] already exists in the map, and then if yes, then add splitter[8] to the value of the that key in the map?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, I've read that. It's just not a suitable answer for my problem..

Comment: you shouldn't be using != to compare Strings in java, you need to use the negation of the .equals() method instead

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if( alldataMap.containsKey(splitter[0]) ) { 
  Double sum = alldataMap.remove(splitter[0]) + Double.parseDouble(splitter[8]);
  allDataMap.put(splitter[0], sum );
} else {
  alldataMap.put(splitter[0], Double.valueOf(splitter[8]) );
}
```

Comment: Also a very right answer (is kinda how i did it now but i still had to make it a double:P) thanks for seeing that and the solution man :)

Comment: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Double
                                          Double sum = alldataMap.remove(splitter[0]) + Double.parseDouble(splitter[8]);
                                                                                      ^
javaFiles\bufferedread.java:49: error: incompatible types: Double cannot be converted to String
                                          alldataMap.put(splitter[0], sum );

Comment: Looks like you have  `Map<String,String>` change it to `Map<String,Double>` :)

Comment: ah its because it isnt made a double in the else statement i think

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) and [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) since Java 8:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

//...

String fruitName = /*whatever*/;
int qty = /*whatever*/;

myMap.putIfAbsent(fruitName, 0);
myMap.compute(fruitName, (k, oldQty) -> oldQty + qty);
```

Comment: Compute is enough in this case

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn You'd need an ugly conditional expression, to see whether it was previously entered such as `(k, oldQty) -> (oldQty == null ? 0 : oldQty) + qty` and I think my way is more readable.

Comment: ah seems interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map#containsKey()` to check for an existing mapping, then if there is one use `Map#get()` to retrieve the value and add the new one, and finally `Map#put()` to store the sum:

```
if(map.containsKey(key))
    map.put(key, map.get(key)+value);
else
    map.put(key, value);
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for the documentation of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

i would use the `merge` for a map :

```
alldataMap.merge(splitter[0], Double.valueOf(splitter[8]), (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal + newVal);
```

From [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key. For example, to either create or append a String msg to a value mapping:

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest the way to it in a loop because that's already done, but I'd suggest a `Streams` solution, in a *unique* line :

```
Map<String, Double> alldataMap = new HashMap<>();
try {
    alldataMap =
            Files.lines(Paths.get("", filepath))
                    .map(str -> str.split(cvsSplitBy))
                    .filter(splitte -> !splitte[0].equals("Voertuig"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(sp -> sp[0],
                            sp -> Double.parseDouble(sp[8].replaceAll(",", ".")),
                            (i1, i2) -> i1 + i2));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(alldataMap); // {Apples=4212.0, Bananas=985.23}
```

The steps are the same :

- Iterate over the lines
- split on the `cvsSplitBy`
- remove lines which starts with `Voertuig` (**!** use `.equals()` and not `!=`)
- build the map following 3 rules :

  - the key is the first `String`
  - the value is second `String` parsed as `Double`
  - if merge is required : sum both

---

Edit, as nobody propose the use of `.getOrDefault()` I give it

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splitter = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    if (!splitter[0].equals("Voertuig")) {
        alldataMap.put(splitter[0],
           alldataMap.getOrDefault(splitter[0], 0.0) + 
                                    Double.parseDouble(splitter[8].replaceAll(",", ".")));
    }
}
```

If tke key already exists, it'll sum, it the key does not exists it'll sum the value with a 0